# When will the pioneers testnet go live?

Tags: testnet

In a recent blog post by IOG [(link)](https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2021/04/08/smart-contracts-%E2%80%93-here-we-come/) the roadmap indicated the Pioneer testnet would go live mid-April to the start of May. Is anyone able to comment/update us on when the testnet will go live?

Answer (score 5):

There is currently no announcement regarding a date. I have seen rumours that the Plutus Pioneer testnet is already up and running (probably caused by a web page that displays timers at certain milestones) - this is not true.